# What is the difference between the following GPO settings?

Tags: windows-server, windows-firewall, group-policy, gpo

While doing some GPO work today and setting up some firewall inbound rules that I want distributed through GP I became confused between these two GPs. They function very similarly, yet I couldn't find any differences.

**Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Inbound Rules**

and

**Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Network > Network Connections > Windows Firewall > Domain Profile > Windows Firewall: Define Inbound Port Exception**

So, what are their diffrences?

Comment: I want people to know I can't show you the policies as there is too much to them, and I am hoping for a experienced windows server professional to see this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two different Group Policy locations for Windows Firewall settings are due to feature differences in the Windows Firewall itself between older and newer Windows OS versions.

**If you are using Windows Vista/Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 or newer operating systems, use this Group Policy path to configure Firewall policies,** as these operating systems have the Windows Firewall *"with Advanced Security"*:

> Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security
>   Settings > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Inbound Rules

**If you are using Windows XP or Windows Server 2003, use *only* the Group Policy path below to configure Firewall policies**.  Reason is because these older  operating systems have the older Windows Firewall without the "*Advanced Security*", and only the Group Policy path shown below will work with these older systems.

> Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates >Network>
>   Network Connections > Windows Firewall > Domain Profile > Windows Firewall: Define Inbound Port Exception

I navigated through a ton of research and stumbled across the answer inside this Windows Server 2008 Firewall training video by ITFreeTraining (published on 9/05/2011), where it is explained at the 25:45 mark:   [Windows Server 2008 Firewall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og6kGDEJ6PU)

Unrelated, but since this is a coding Q&A site, you might want to take a look at [managing Group Policy through PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx).

Comment: I am back! Sorry I was away for so long!

Comment: The most beautiful explanation ever! Thank you and I apologize for the delay!